# Create flag based on column with multiple values per unique ID in R

Tags: r, variables, conditional-statements, unique

I've searched Stack Overflow and cannot find a similar question... please refer me if you know of one.

I have a data frame "data" that looks something like this, but with over 80 million rows and millions of possibilities for VarA:

```
ID YEAR  VarA      
1  2014  a     
1  2015  a      
1  2014  b             
1  2015  c             
2  2014  a        
2  2015  b        
2  2016  c
```

I would like to create a flag where for every unique ID, we count a conditional VarA once. For example, if I want to flag all instances where VarA could be "a", "b", or "c", I want them counted once per unique individual:

```
ID YEAR  VarA  Flagabc     
1  2014  a     1  
1  2015  a     0
1  2014  b     0      
1  2015  c     0      
2  2014  a     1 
2  2015  b     0 
2  2016  c     0
```

I have tried to first reshape my data to wideform and create flags:

```
    data.w <- reshape(data=data, direction="wide", idvar="ID", timevar="YEAR")
    data.w$Flagabc <- data.w$VarA %in% c("a", "b", "c")
```

But it seems only the first value of VarA of every year is included, while my data has 1000s of VarA's per person per year. I want my flag to sift through every possible VarA for each unique person and only flag it once, regardless of repetition by year or by condition, when the condition is satisfied. Because there are also so many different possible VarA's, I do not want to reshape it using dcast(melt where every unique VarA gets its own column.

I'd like to avoid looping because my data set is so large... But if that's what it comes down to, would like help in writing the appropriate code.

Does anyone have any ideas or different approaches I can take?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm a bit unsure what your goal is -- to find out which values of "VarA" each individual has at least once? Where does the importance of flagging the first year of occurrence come in?

Comment: Hi! My goal with Flagabc is to see how many unique individuals have a, b, or c. I also need to make flags for when VarA= d, e, or f, and so on. Regardless of what year or how many times the same value of VarA shows up, I want my Flagabc=1 once per person (as long as a, b, or c shows up in that individual's VarA). It is less about the first year of occurrence as it is about a, b, or c existing in an individual's VarA at all. Does this make sense?

Comment: Based on that, it sounds like you could count up the number of occurrences for every combination of ID and VarA, while ignoring year. Any count that is greater than zero would mean that ID exhibits that VarA at least once? Or are you meaning that "Flagabc" means counting IDs that contain a OR b OR c at least once, but ignoring values d/e/f (etc)?

Comment: I believe I'm looking for the latter. Ultimately, with Flagabc, I want a count of how many unique ID's have a, b, or c in their millions of different VarA's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using data.table, it's a one liner.

```
> setDT(df)
> df[,Flagabc := 0]
> df[df[VarA %in% c('a','b','c'), .I[1], by=ID]$V1, Flagabc:=1]
   ID YEAR VarA Flagabc
1:  1 2014    a       1
2:  1 2015    a       0
3:  1 2014    b       0
4:  1 2015    c       0
5:  2 2014    a       1
6:  2 2015    b       0
7:  2 2016    c       0
```

Explanation

- `df[VarA %in% c('a','b','c'), .I[1], by=ID]$V1` This part selects the indexes of first row of each group while satisfying the given condition

Comment: Thank you so much! This did exactly what I wanted.